# Array is being changed to String inside a arrow function

Tags: javascript

I am defining my variable as array and pushing values inside it.
When I try to access this variable inside another method and apply push function on it, It says, Push is not defined.
When I check the typeof of this variable  it shows as String.

Any suggestions?

```
recipients = [];

....

 handleEmailChange(event) {

        const {name , value , dataset: {recipientIndex} } = event.target;
        this.toAddresses[recipientIndex][name] = value; 

    }

handleChange(event) {
        this.recipients = event.detail.value;
    }

 handleSend(event){

        this.toAddresses.forEach ( (address) => {

            const email = address.emailAddress;
            this.recipients.push(email);
```

Comment: please share complete code snippet

Comment: And what you are assigning here, `this.recipients = event.detail.value`, is also definitively an array?

Comment: [ask] -> [mcve]

Comment: User inputs their email in an input box and clicks on a button. Event.detail.value is that email that i assign to this.recipients.

Comment: "*Event.detail.value is that email that i assign to this.recipients.*" and isn't that what changes `this.recipients` to a string?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it caused because in the function `handleChange` you wrote `this.recipients = event.detail.value` where `event.detail.value` is probably a string type.

Comment: Thanks sasaddd. Do you have a workaround because obviously I will be a getting a string from my inputs.